# Watson Knowledge Studio - Storage error

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-nlu, watson-knowledge-studio

Have created a model in Watson Knowledge Studio and deploying it in NLU service of Bluemix. Recently I get the below error while deploying. "This operation cannot be completed because the model size exceeds the subscription storage size 5 GB." What could be the reason ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bill wrote, WKS has small storage limitation for Free plan and creating snapshots of Machine Learning models might hit the limitation.

I believe you have many snapshots of ML model. Could you please delete unnecessary snapshots from your projects? If you have multiple projects on your WKS tenant (server instance), please consider the total number of snapshots across the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Which plan are you using for the Natural Language Understanding service? The Free and Lite plans have limits to the size of your custom model. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/natural-language-understanding/customizing.html): 
"The Natural Language Understanding Free plan limits the size and performance of your custom model. To test a custom model to its full extent, you will need to use it with the Natural Language Understanding Standard plan."
See the service entry in the [Bluemix Catalog](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding) for more options.

Comment: Side note: some of your edits are discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356179/578411). You might want to take note of that and maybe share your thoughts.